# How to check null/undefined string value when get from localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have use case like this:

```
const language = "en"/"jp"/null/undefined; 
// Here is my language value that I get from server
// It could be "en", "jp" , null or undefined


// I set language value into localStorage
localStorage.setItem("language", language)

// Somewhere I get language from localStorage
localStorage.getItem("language");
```

My problem is when I get `language` from localStorage with value is `null` or `undefined`. The result that I receive is a string (`"null"` or `"undefined"`)

In current code I checking manual like this:

```
const getLanguage = localStorage.getItem("language");
const defalutLanguage = "en";
const currentLanguage = ( getLanguage && getLanguage !== "null" 
      && getLanguage !== "undefined" ) ? getLanguage : defalutLanguage
```

**But, I know that is a bad way. So, Is there any way to fast check with my case ?**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` will never return `undefined` anyway

Comment: Looks reasonable, but unless you *need* to differentiate between null and undefined, consider calling `setItem` with the empty string instead, when the `language` gotten is falsey. Easier to not input data you're gonna ignore later

Comment: @Bravo The *string* stored in localStorage is `'undefined'` here. Kinda weird

Comment: No, localStorage.getItem will return an string "undefined" or string "null"

Comment: @CertainPerformance - ahh, OK - pays to read the whole question I guess :p

Comment: the result from the top code is that `localStorage.getItem("language");` returns the string `"NaN"` - so, not sure where `"null"` or `"undefined"` would be coming from

Comment: @Bravo, that values I use to save into `localStorage`. Somewhere in my project, I want to get `language` from `localStorage`. But when I `getItem` with null value, the resulst will be `"null"` not `null` value

Comment: @jdn so when you get the response from the server as null or undefined do you need to set it to localstorage? why do you require to set null or undefined as language. if any dependency is there you can basically check whether language is there in localStorage. So You have two cases either en or null || undefined, so basically if its a valid value set it to local otherwise dont set it

Answer (score -1):

Please use JSON parser

```
const language = "en"/"jp"/null/undefined; 
localStorage.setItem("language", JSON.stringify({ language }) );

const getLanguage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("language")).language;
const defalutLanguage = "en";
const currentLanguage = getLanguage ? getLanguage : defalutLanguage;
```

Comment: No, with `"null" or "undefined"`, you can use `JSON.parse`. But with an string like `"en" or "jp"`, this way to throw an Error

Comment: @jdn Please check now

Comment: Your way work fine. But in my case, I don't want to save an object into `localStorage`.

Comment: @jdn Sorry i dont see any other way